# Match and replace very specific number

Tags: regular-expression, search

I would like to replace every number `n` in my document with `n+1`. Easy:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\+\)/\=(submatch(0)+1)/g
```

Now I would like to replace every number `n` with `n+1`, only when the number has exactly three digits. Look behind/ahead to the rescue!

```
:%s/[0-9]\@<!\([0-9]\{3}\)[0-9]\@!/\=(submatch(0)+1)/g
```

But now I would like to replace every number `n` with `n+1`, only when the number is between 42 and 1337. Can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of moving more logic into the regular expression, move more logic into the replacement.

```
function! IncrementIf(fn, n)
    if a:fn(a:n)
        return n + 1
    endif
    return n
endfunction
:%s/\(\d\+\)/\=IncrementIf({x -> x >= 42 && x <= 1337}, submatch(0))/g
```

You can even generalize this a bit by using [partials](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#Partial).

```
function! If(fn, t, f, ...)
    if call(a:fn, a:000)
        return call(a:t, a:000)
    endif
    return call(a:f, a:000)
endfunction

let Inc = function('If', [{x -> x >= 42 && x <= 1337}, {x -> x + 1}, {x -> x}])

:%s/\([0-9]\+\)/\=Inc(submatch(0))/g
```